Experiment for generating electricity from high heated and pressurized gas
Experiment for generating electricity from high heated and pressurized gas.
While playing ball at school, many of us had the experience about feeling the energy from the ball hitting it upon the ground, which is definitely potential load of electricity flowing through our hands into the arms.
So, there could be a way to make this electrical load more automatically by stuffing gas into a volume of container which is isolated by capacitors and bobbins. Heating this pressurized gas will make its molecules more disordered and accelerated moving across from one point to another. Well-known is that every atom and molecule has a magnetic field surrounding its own diameter. This means when the molecules are moving speedy and crosses other ones, magnetic field of each will be excited, so  that a differential voltage will exist. Therefore, the absorbing of this potential load will be charged in batteries and can be used for further purposes.
The gas formula:
$ P . V = n . R . T $
I researched on internet about the electrical field around atoms and could find out the electrons are responsible for this surrounding, namely orbitals. Quantum scientists are guessing there could be more beyond these electrons.
My questions are the following:
Can the atoms be abused for automatic generating electricity with conditions like predicted above and if atoms have an electric field like any other object that we might know?
Gravitation force by distance of masses:
$ F = (m1 . m2 . G ) / d^2  $


Since the atoms will be moving equally as much in opposite directions, the electric field generated by moving magnetic fields will all cancel out macroscopically. There could be local fields as they pass each other though.
I don't understand the relevancy of the two formulas or the picture in your question.
